# Program works but when input is invalid it keeps looping c++

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

inline double multplication(double num1, double num2);
inline double division(double num1, double num2);
inline double addition(double num1, double num2);
inline double substraction(double num1, double num2);


int main()
{
        cout << "Welcome to 'The calculator' just enter a number the     operator '*, /, + and -' then the second number enjoy" << endl;
        char redo = 'r'; double result = 0; int cnt = 0;
        while (redo == 'r' || redo == 'R')
        {
                try
                {
                        if (cnt > 0)
                                cout << "Ok same rules as before" << endl;
                        int num1 = 0, num2 = 0; char inputedOperator = '*';
                        cin >> num1 >> inputedOperator >> num2;

                        switch (inputedOperator)
                        {
                        case('*') :
                                result = multplication(num1, num2);
                                break;
                        case('/') :
                                result = division(num1, num2);
                                break;
                        case('+') :
                                result = addition(num1, num2);
                                break;
                        case('-') :
                                result = substraction(num1, num2);
                                break;

                        default:
                                throw runtime_error("Invalid operator");
                        }
                }
                catch (runtime_error err)
                {
                        cout << err.what() << endl;
                        cout << "Enter y to redo or anykey to exit" << endl;
                        cin >> redo;
                        ++cnt;
                        continue;
                }

                cout << "The answer is " << result << "\nPlease enter y to redo or anykey to exit" << endl;
                cin >> redo;
                ++cnt;
        }

        cout << "Thanks for using" << endl;

        return 0;
}

inline double multplication(double num1, double num2)
{
        return num1 * num2;
}
inline double division(double num1, double num2)
{
        return num1 / num2;
}
inline double addition(double num1, double num2)
{
        return num1 + num2;
}
inline double substraction(double num1, double num2)
{
        return num1 - num2;
}
```

Whenever I run '3 * 2' as the input it works fine but for '3 * d' it keeps looping at the end of my code also '3 d 3' is fine since it just sais invalid operator. So my question is why does it keep looping and how do I fix it?

Comment: Hint: check ``cin.fail ()``

Comment: Add the code to the question

Comment: I don't see why you need to show us a full blown program.  Why not write a simple `main` function, 3 or 4 lines, that demonstrates the issue of invalid input and then post that?

Comment: @Tibo I put it so after cin >> num1 >> inputedOperator >> num2; it outputs the cin.fail() and when it goes into the loop it outputs 1 but when im good its 0 so do I do something like cin.clear()?

Comment: Note that those `inline` markers have no effect because the definitions of those functions are not visible at the points where they are called.

Comment: If I put them where I declared them will it? @PeteBecker

Comment: Don't throw an exception and catch it in the same function. Exceptions are for problems that can't be handled locally. Just move the code from the catch clause to the default case and remove the `try` and `catch` blocks.

Comment: Looking how you use inline keyword with function *declaration* (no function body), note that inline keyword only makes sense when you have function *definition* in a .h file. Also, inline keyword is only tangentially related to inlining optimization, it does not enable it by itself, and compiler does not generally take it as a hint to try extra hard to inline the function.

Comment: What happens if I use that exception multiple times locally? @PeteBecker

Comment: So I added cin.clear(); and cin.ignore(numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n'); now I understand cin.clear and cin.ignore but why (numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n')?

Answer (score 0):

added

```
if (cin.fail())
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
}
```

To clear the invalid input and buffer. Found info on cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2957/